# Custom Rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Suppose I have an `events` controller. If I request `/events` by `GET` it will respond with `index` action in news controller, this view will display future events.

I want to add a new action called `past`, it is like `index`, which return an array of `Event`s but with another query.

I have added to `routes.rb` this chunk:

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    get :past
  end
end
```

and I this chuck to `events_controller`:

```
def history
  @events => Event.past
  render :template => 'index'
end
```

But when I request `http://127.0.0.1:3000/events/past` in browser it does not work, in log are thrown these lines:

```
Started GET "/events/past" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-02 19:32:01 -0500
  Processing by EventsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"past"}
```

And finally here you have `rake routes` output:

```
            events GET    /events(.:format)                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
             event GET    /events/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
       past_events GET    /events/past(.:format)             {:action=>"past", :controller=>"events"}
  contact_us_event POST   /events/:id/contact_us(.:format)   {:action=>"contact_us", :controller=>"events"}
                   GET    /events(.:format)                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
                   POST   /events(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"events"}
         new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"events"}
        edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"}
                   GET    /events/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
                   PUT    /events/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"events"}
                   DELETE /events/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"events"}
```

Other test was check routes using Rails console:

```
$ script/rails c
1.9.2-p318 :001 > rs = ActionController::Routing::Routes
1.9.2-p318 :002 > rs.recognize_path "/events/past", :method => :get
 => {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :id=>"past"}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What does the `rake routes` command show you for events routes?

Comment: @mguymon Hi, I have added `rake routes` output to post. Thank you.

Comment: You said you put `get :past` but `rake routes` shows `history` instead. Are you sure it isn't `get :history`?

Comment: @BrandonTilley Sorry, It was a typo, because I need to write it manually.

Comment: So this is basic Rails plumbing and your code looks valid. What is obvious from the routing info and history method, the code shown is not actually what is used and having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on routes precedence, here you have a `routes.rb` chunk that works:

```
resources :events, :only => [:index, :show] do
  get 'past', :on => :collection
  post 'contact_us', :on => :member
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
resources :events do
  get :past, :to => "events#past"
end
```

I don't think you need the collection context. (And you might not need the :to part)

### Update

Another way to do it is to put the event call above the resource. Assuming you don't need the collection with it.

```
get 'events/past', :to => "events#past"
resources :events
```

Should provide you with the correct routes.

For reference: [Rails 3 routes: How to avoid conflict with 'show' action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982398/rails-3-routes-how-to-avoid-conflict-with-show-action)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion generate this route rule:

`event_past GET    /events/:event_id/past                          {:action=>"past", :controller=>"events"}`

And I want something like this:

`past_event GET    /events/past(.:format)                              {:action=>"past", :controller=>"events"}`

or something like default index route, which get all models in database:

`events GET    /events(.:format)                                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}`

The main idea is to list events like in `index`.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about the :id on those. Sorry, it is late. Have you tried just going at it directly with `get 'events/past', :to => "events#past"`?